# Link to all ~ files automatically shown on Desktop, but I want to show only the Dock

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, desktop-icons, gnome-tweaks

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Now a symbolic link  to every file in the home directory appears along with the Dock in the initial screen. I would prefer only the Dock and otherwise a clean desktop.

Using the tweak tool and the '*Installed Extensions*' portion of the gnome-shell-extensions page I have turned off allow desktop icons setting but it always resets to on.

Comment: I'm happy to know that pomsky's answer worked. But since this is a Q&A site, you need not to include what worked for you unless it is different from the already exisiting answer. You can mark pomsky's answer as accepted by clicking in grey check mark on the left of the answer and you *may* upvote the answer as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the pre-installed '**Extensions**' application in Ubuntu 20.04 to turn off the '*Desktop Icons*' extension. That would get rid of the icons from your desktop.

You can also launch the application from Terminal by running the `gnome-extensions-app` command.